# Navbar links/items same size with CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation

Here's the code I got from a css button generator I was wondering how to make them all the same size instead of the button adjusting to the text length.

```
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #42aaff 0%,
        #003366);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#42aaff),
        to(#003366));
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #003366;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    box-shadow:
        0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.7),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
```

Comment: Remove `Left` and `Right` Padding, Give a specific `width`.

Answer (score 0):

Just give them all a fixed width according to your largest content.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it with fixed px or percentage. But the trick is to then do text-align:center and also I'd throw them into a list:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CfjcG

Comment: Or `em` which is probably more robust.

Answer (score 0):

well... you need to make an element out of it, that code is to just give you the effects you need for whatever you designed on the button creator, you need to apply it to an element that has a specific size.. for example

```
.buttons{
    width:60px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    (all the button stuff)
}
```

if you want it a different size just change the value of the width and height... this should do it.. let me know if it works.. :)